# Merge char* arrays to uint16_t

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to merge a char*-array into a `uint16_t`. This is my code so far:

```
char* arr = new char[2]{0};
arr[0] = 0x0; // Binary: 00000000
arr[1] = 0xBE; // Binary: 10111110

uint16_t merged = (arr[0] << 8) + arr[1]; 
cout << merged << " As Bitset: " << bitset<16>(merged) << endl;
```

I was expecting `merged` to be `0xBE`, or in binary `00000000 10111110`.

But the output of the application is:

```
65470 As Bitset: 1111111110111110
```

*In the following descriptions I'm reading bits from left to right*.

So `arr[1]` is at the right position, which is the last 8 bits. 
The first 8 bits however are set to `1`, which they should not be.

Also, if I change the values to

```
arr[0] = 0x1; // Binary: 00000001
arr[1] = 0xBE; // Binary: 10111110
```

The output is:

`0000000010111110`

Again, `arr[1]` is at the right position. But now the first 8 bits are `0`, whereas the last on of the first 8 should be `1`.

Basically what I wan't to do is append `arr[1]` to `arr[0]` and interpret the new number as whole.

Comment: Why not use `unsigned char`s?

Comment: `char* arr = new char[2]{0};`  Did you really need to use `new[]` here?  `char arr[2] = {0};`

Comment: I just wrote this code as an example, so I don't have to copy 100 lines to see where the data is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `char` is signed type in your case, and you are left-shifting `0xBE` vhich is interpreted as signed negative value (`-66` in a likely case of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)).

It is undefined behavior according to the standard. In practice it is often results in extending the sign bit, hence leading ones.

> **3.9.1 Fundamental types**
> ....
>
> It is implementationdefined
>   whether a char object can hold negative values.
>
> ---
>
> **5.8 Shift operators**
> ....
>
> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned
>   type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2`<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable
>   in the result type. Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1×2`<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable
>   in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the
>   resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign to the wider type *before* shifting, otherwise you're shifting away<sup>†</sup> your high bits before they ever even hit the only variable here that's big enough to hold them.

```
uint16_t merged = arr[0];
merged <<= 8;
merged += arr[1];
```

Or, arguably:

```
const uint16_t merged = ((uint16_t)arr[0] << 8) + arr[1];
```

You also may want to consider converting through `unsigned char` first to avoid oddities with the high bit set. Try out a few different values in your unit test suite and see what happens.

<sub><sup>†</sup> Well, your program has undefined behaviour from this out-of-range shift, so who knows what might happen!</sub>

Comment: "_You need to assign to the wider type before shifting, , otherwise you're shifting away your high bit_". Is not it a part of the standard `char->int` integral promotion? It would not be needed in case of `unsigned char`.

Comment: I tried this already, did also not work. The other answer works.

Comment: @AlexD: there is no standard `char->unsigned char->int` integral promotion, is my point

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure. My concern is that the quoted sentence, if you put it as the first sentence in the post, out of context, may sound as a general rule that one always has to widen, regardless of signed/unsigned discussion.

Comment: @AlexD: Oh, true, I was thinking of the problems of "merging" into e.g. an `uint64_t`, which integral promotion doesn't do for you. So I suppose the widening indeed isn't the crucial point here.